# Entity Framework Inheritance: Foreign Key in the same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity framework.  I am using inheritance, which puts different object types in the same table (via discriminator).

However, this causes an issue as relationships between objects in the same table can not be illustrated via a foreign key.  Any suggestions how to solve?  Some code below.

```
public abstract class DivBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset DateModified { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ModifiedByUserId { get; set; }
}
public abstract class DivClaim : DivBase
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string ClaimType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DivUserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
}

public class DivCustomer : DivClaim
{
    public ICollection<DivProject> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class DivProject : DivClaim, IDivEvent
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DivCustomer Customer { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to store all abstractions in a single table?

Answer (score 0):

In this case where your base class just defines common attributes for all your entities, simply exclude the base class from the DbContext.  Each of your Entities will get its own table, but they will all have the properties inherited from the base class.  You just won't be able to query over the base entity type.

Comment: The reason i want them in the same table, is so they share the same pool of Ids.  This allows me to test claims from one set of Ids.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you're on SQL Server (or some others) you could use a single shared SEQUENCE to generate key values. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15  And you really don't want all your entities in one table.  The Foreign Key problem would only be the first of many problems.

Comment: How would you go about using sequence with EF?

Comment: Sequences - EF Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/sequences